# How to solve this winsock error?

Tags: c++

```
C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\test - fail\winsock2 socket server.cpp: In function `int _tmain()':
C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\test - fail\winsock2 socket server.cpp:48: error: `getaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\test - fail\winsock2 socket server.cpp:59: error: `freeaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\test - fail\winsock2 socket server.cpp:68: error: `freeaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\Chan\Desktop\test - fail\winsock2 socket server.cpp:74: error: `freeaddrinfo' was not declared in this scope
```

Using this header files

```
#include "winsock2.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "WS2tcpip.h"
```

Comment: Just a guess... Switch off UNICODE compilation, or use the Unicode versions of these functions, specifically [`GetAddrInfoW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738519(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`FreeAddrInfoW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737912(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The header file WS2tcpip.h uses this define:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
```

This means that in your build you should define _WIN32_WINNT to 0x600 (Vista) or higher. This means that the API you want doesn't exist in WinXP.

Comment: That seems like the source of the error, though apparently the header file disagrees with the documentation (and with observable reality). The unicode version was added with Windows XP SP2, and the non-unicode version has existed since W2k.